# Hyper-V no network found

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I created a Windows 10 VM on my desktop (win 10 pro), and imported it on my laptop (win 10 pro).
All went well, except for the internet.

I use the default virtual switch.
In the guest OS I have no network adapter when I go there via the network icon at the bottom right corner (which has a red X and says 'no conections available')

When I go to the device manager in the guest os I see this:
[image]
I tried to uninstall that device and add it again, but that did not make any difference.

I used to have internet on it when it was still on my desktop.

This is the device manager with hidden items:

[image]

Comment: More details about "it didn't work", please.

Comment: changed it to 'that didn't make any difference'

Comment: I added the hidden devices (didn't know they existed). What exactly is the Hyper-V network device panel?

Answer (score 1):

Correct my if I'm wrong, but I believe that the Default Switch is Internal by default, which allows the  VMs on the switch to communicate with each other, but additionally can communicate to the Hyper-V host itself.

This may be causing you issues, you may have to change it to external so that it works through the chosen network adapter

Regards

Comment: That sounds logical, and when I read about creating a virtual switch it indeed should be external, and it is also true that the default one is internal. However.... When I create a new VM on this laptop, it also uses the default switch, and it DOES have internet.